# fail at submiting 2d array into unit test laravel

Tags: php, laravel, testing

I have an api that recives 3 inputs as below :

```
room_id[]
from_date
to_date
```

now room id is an array of ids for room my test for this api is like below :

```
  $response = $this->json('POST', '/api/v1/accommodationbookingapi', [array(['room_id' => '1']),'from_date' =>'2019-04-2','to_date'=>'2019-04-2']);
        dd($response);`
```

and the message of that dd is like below :

```
  "message" => "Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::cleanBindings() must be of the type array, null given, called in /home/farshad/my-projects/tika_acco/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php on line 870"
```

I have tested that in postman and that's working fine but test seems like it does not recognize the room_id array that I am sending to it. so as to input how can send an array to API ??

Comment: try `room_id => ['1']` instead of this one `array(['room_id' => '1'])`

Comment: yes thats right u can make it answer so i accep it as the correct one

Comment: my pleasure helping you. thanks. I post it an answer as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `room_id => ['1']` instead of this one `array(['room_id' => '1'])`